# Future Britain, no kids born, NOT Children of Men

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

A book I read in the UK approx 2010 but I think it was older.
Can't recall anything of the cover.

It's set in a future Britain where no (or very, very few) kids have born for at least a couple of decades. Near mediaeval society for some reason.
It's more  a series of related vignettes featuring the protagonist wandering about the country asking questions.
He's only called by his surname (but I don't remember it!)

He goes to a cathedral where they are holding a "special service" because the vicar is displaying the only two kids for miles around. It's a young girl with a withered arm and a Downs Syndrome boy (or maybe the reverse) but the elderly congregation is crying with longing while they look at them standing at the pulpit.

Then our MC is walking through a town and he hurriedly crosses the street to see a woman pushing a pram, however, when he leans in, he sees the child is actually a poodle pup dressed in lace and the mother is near insane with desperate longing for a child.

Then he's at a crowded theatre watching a musical performance because they have a young boy as part of the show, however he manages to get backstage and, in the dressing rooms, he discovers it's actually a midget with skilful makeup.

He manages to track down a couple where the woman is pregnant but he loses contact, when he meets them again she's no longer pregnant and denies she ever was....he has a mystery to solve!

Eventually he learns that there is like a secret organisation helping people to avoid their rare kids being treated as freaks and having crowds follow them on the streets etc - plus I think there's a government department that puts kids into an institution for protection

There is a massive forest across a river, he helps another couple get their baby across and it's taken away to be foster raised amongst other kids in near normality.

He walks away hoping that, when they reach puberty, the fosterlings won't have the same fertility problems as current society.

This is **not** Graybeard by Brian W Aldiss

Comment: I haven't read it, so I don't know how closely it matches, but Greybeard by Brian Aldiss has the theme of an aging population with no children born.   https://sfbook.com/greybeard.htm   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greybeard

Comment: No sorry, not Greybeard - I've just had a good look at online info but it's not the one